# How can I set the CSS include directory for a jquery UI component?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Right now, the script is trying to find the image at:

> ./images/ui-bg_gloss-wave_35_f6a828_500x100.png

But I'd rather have it look here:

> ./css/ui-lightness/images/ui-bg_gloss-wave_35_f6a828_500x100.png

How do I set the relative path for a jquery ui component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either change it directly in the `CSS`, if you have access (i.e. you're serving the `CSS` file).

or

Override the definition with another from your own `CSS`.

`jQuery UI` provides hooks `class` names for you to target and style.

Comment: There's no global setting I can adjust? I have to edit the code for the component?

Comment: You can customize the `CSS` to your needs and could go as far as not including their `CSS` - but create your own.